# Getting logged in user not the user running the program C#, Windows

Tags: c#, windows

How to get the current logged in user?

I already tried

```
Environment.CurrentUser
```

and

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().
```

Both of them return the user that is running the programm.

Thanks for your help.

Kind Regards,
Sandro

Comment: We need to know more about your setup, how is the user logged in?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951745/how-to-get-currently-logged-on-user-name-and-account-typeadmin-nonadmin-when-t

Comment: The user is logged in using a domain service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the directive `System.Management`.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

Alternatively check out [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244000/find-out-the-current-users-username-when-multiple-users-are-logged-on).